# return inverse string selection in python

Tags: python

I have a python snippet that returns the contents within two strings using regex.

```
res = re.search(r'Presets = {(.*)Version = 1,', data, re.DOTALL)
```

What I now want to do is return the two strings surrounding this inner part. Keep in mind this is a multiline string. How can I get the bordering strings, the beginning and end part in a two part list would be ideal.

```
data = """{
    data = {
        friends = {
            max = 0 0,
            min = 0 0,
        },
        family = {
            cars = {
                van = "honda",
                car = "ford",
                bike = "trek",
            },
            presets = {
                location = "italy",
                size = 10,
                travelers = False,
            },
            version = 1,
        },
    },
    stuff = {
        this = "great",
    },
}"""

import re


res = re.search(r'presets = {(.*)version = 1,', data, re.DOTALL)
print res.groups(1)
```

In this case I would want to return the beginning string:

```
data = """{
    data = {
        friends = {
            max = 0 0,
            min = 0 0,
        },
        family = {
            cars = {
                van = "honda",
                car = "ford",
                bike = "trek",
            },
```

And the end string:

```
        },
    },
    stuff = {
        this = "great",
    },
}"""
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than the "inner" or "outter" strings?

Comment: Please add an example of hte desired output for the example above.

Comment: @BrandonM updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is really not a good tool for parsing these strings, but you can use `re.split` to achieve what you wanted. It can even combine the 2 tasks into one:

```
begin, middle, end = re.split(r'presets = \{(.*)version = 1,', data,
    flags=re.DOTALL)
```

`re.split` splits the string at matching positions; ordinarily the separator is not in the resulting list. However, if the regular expression contains capturing groups, then the matching contents of the first group is returned in the place of the delimiter.

Comment: you say it's not ideal, what would you recommend then?

Comment: No, regex is not ideal. And the format isn't ideal either.

Comment: i agree with that, i sadly can't change the format.